# PyQt5 Convert 2d np array to QImage

Tags: numpy, pyqt5, qt5

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
import numpy as np
import sys

def print_np():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = QWidget()
    label = QLabel()

    img = np.ones((500, 500))
    qImg = QPixmap(QImage(img.data, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], QImage.Format_Indexed8))
    label.setPixmap(qImg)

    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(label)
    win.setLayout(vbox)
    win.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this code, I am trying to display 2d np array on QtWindow.

I am expecting to see a white square, but I keep getting a weird display as below.

I believe its because wrong QImage.Format (data type), so I tried every option but didn't help.

https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QImage.html#PySide.QtGui.QImage

Should I change np array to jpg or png first, as examples in documentation?

[image]

Comment: Why have you removed the `#import` statements? It makes your code impossible to run and it's therefore harder to assist you.

Comment: Are you hoping to display colours in your image? If so, it needs to be of shape `500,500,3` to accommodate 3 RGB channels and have type RGB888. If you only want black/white/greys, your shape is correct but you need to tell Qt is is greyscale.

Comment: Your array is float64, when you needed int8: `img = np.ones((500, 500), dtype=dtype=np.uint8)`. And maybe you also want the RGB version `img = np.ones((3, 500, 500) ...`

Comment: `
img = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), dtype=np.uint8) 
    qImg = QPixmap(
        QImage(img.data, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], QImage.Format_RGB888))
    label.setPixmap(qImg)
`

Both np.zeros and ones give me a black image. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

- Your `dtype` needs to be `np.uint8` when you create your Numpy image array
- Your `format` needs to be `QImage.Format_RGB888`
- Your pixels need to bigger than `0` or `1` to show up, the full range is 0..255

So, with that in mind:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
import numpy as np
import sys

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = QWidget()
    label = QLabel()

    img = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    # Turn up red channel to full scale
    img[...,0] = 255
    qImg = QPixmap(QImage(img.data, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], QImage.Format_RGB888))
    label.setPixmap(qImg)

    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(label)
    win.setLayout(vbox)
    win.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

[image]

++ (to convert 2D image as black vs white)

```
img = np.zeros((500, 500), dtype=np.uint8)
img[250:, :] = 255

qImg = QPixmap(QImage(img.data, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], QImage.Format_Grayscale8))
```

It will create a window

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, Qt, QImage, QPixmap, image processing.

Comment: @Sean Rather than `QImage.Format_Indexed8`, you should probably use `QImage.Format_Grayscale8` to be sure of tones.

Comment: I edited once more, btw thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Cool, and thanks also to @Demi-Lune Good luck with your project and remember, questions (and answers) are free, so come back if you get stuck.